# JAVA help ;Use a while loop to build a string that is a single line consisting of asterisks

Tags: java

The question I am working on is:

Use a while loop to build a string that is a single line consisting of asterisks'. The number of asterisks is determined by the parameter numberOfStars and cannot be a negative number. Return the String

The code i have so far is:

```
public String Question1(int numberOfStars) //cannot change this line

    {
        String str = "*";
        while (numberOfStars > 0)
                {numberOfStars--;
        return str;}
    }
```

The error eclipse gives:
This method must return a result of type String

Thanks,

Comment: @YassinHajaj no they are not, there is one after the `return str;` line.

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand? What gets returned if numberofStars starts with -1?

Comment: @aguibert Yes sorry, I do not know how I've not seen it.

Comment: if numberOfStars = -1 I get zero stars, if numberOfStars is 0 or any positvie number I only get a single star.

Comment: public String Question1(int numberOfStars)
 {
  String str = "*";
  String total = "";
  while (numberOfStars > 0){
  total = total + str;
  numberOfStars--;
  }
  return total;
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this compile error would be much easier for you to see for yourself if you use standard code formatting (see code below for standard formatting).  The compile error is because if the while loop is never entered your function would never return a value:

```
public String Question1(int numberOfStars) {
    String str = "*";
    while (numberOfStars > 0) {
        numberOfStars--;
        return str;
    }
    // compiler thinks: "what if the code gets here?"
    // no String would be returned
}
```

Yes, you said that `numberOfStars` must be non negative, but the compiler doesn't know that.  Also, `numberOfStars` could be 0, in which case the loop would still never be entered.

To solve the compile error, you need to add a return statement outside of the while loop, in case the loop never gets entered like this:

```
public String Question1(int numberOfStars) {
    String str = "*";
    while (numberOfStars > 0) {
        numberOfStars--;
        return str;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Now, this "fixed" code will still not return a string containing the specified number of stars like you want it to, but I'll let you figure that part out yourself, since it looks like you are trying to learn programming.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Added the extra return line, fixed the error. No just need to figure out why my while loop does not actually return more stars, instead my code just prints a single *.